# Strange behavior of solidity program

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, evm

After a long debugging I found that I had two following problems in a private ethereum network using geth:

- If I have a **require** statement then the code is not executed on the EVM. The solution I found was to use a boolean and a **if (test) { ...}** statement
- Some code did not work to the end (that is emission of **emit Statement(...)** in my case). The problem appeared to be insufficient gas. The raw solution to that was to double the gas as given by **eth_estimate_gas**.

What would be the *real* solution to those problems? What documentation exist about this kind of problems?

Comment: Please share your code (only the part relevant to this question). Your verbal description is rather obscure, and it does not provide a clear picture.

Comment: What does the genesis file of your private network looks like? What version of solidity compiler are you using? The REVERT opcode is new since byzantinum fork, if your genesis doesn't have those opcodes enabled and the compiler is less than two years then the compiled bytecode will fail with invalid OPCODE. Gas estimation is tricky. What tools/framework do you use? I usually add 10% on top of estimation.

Comment: After a long search, I found the solution to the problem. I was calling the eth_estimateGas with a different code than the one with the rawTransaction. More precisely the value array was unset in the eth_estimateGas while it was set in the rawTransaction call.